# Using multiple conditions within case statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, case

My aim is to join the users and products tables on the Product_ID. I have attached the users table and products table for your reference below.

users table:
[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C25kB.jpg)

[image]

products table: [Products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkNI.jpg)

[image]

When **product_ID is 7**, I need to look into the **application date** in the **users** table and compare if it falls within the **first_day_active** and **last_day_active** in the **products** table to get the **Commission** rate. I used the below query and it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
CASE

WHEN (users.product_ID = 7 AND users.application_date BETWEEN ('2017-04-01','2017-06-01')) THEN products.commission
WHEN (users.product_ID = 7 AND users.application_date BETWEEN ('2017-06-02','2017-09-01')) THEN products.commission
WHEN users.product_ID = 7 AND users.application_date > '2017-09-02' THEN products.commission
ELSE "Something Fishy" END AS TESTING
```

Comment: *I have attached the users table and products table for your reference below.* No, you have attached Products table screenshot twice.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically:

```
SELECT Users.Name, 
       Products.Product_name,
       Products.Comission
FROM Users
JOIN Products ON Users.Application_id = Products.Application_id
             AND Users.Application_Date BETWEEN Products.First_day
                                            AND COALESCE(Products.Last_day, Users.Application_Date)
WHERE products.Active = 0
```